# Let $K_i$ denote the number of outcomes that occur exactly $i$ times, $i = 0, 1 \cdots$ . Compute $\mathbb E[K_i ] $ and Var$(K_i )$.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

The number of trials to be performed is a Poisson random variable with mean $\lambda$. Each trial has $n$ possible outcomes and, independent of everything else, results in outcome number $i$ with probability $P_i , \sum_{i=1}^n P_i=1 $. Let $K_i$ denote the number of outcomes that occur exactly $i$ times, $i = 0, 1 \cdots$ . Compute $\mathbb E[K_i ] $ and Var$(K_i )$.

**Attempt:** Let the random variable $N$ denote the total number of trials and $X^j_i = 1 $ if outcome $j$ occurs $i$ times and $0$ otherwise. $j = 1,\cdots,n$

Then the r.v $K_i = \sum_{j=1}^N X_i^j$ denotes the total number of outcomes that occur exactly $i$ times.

$$\mathbb E[K_i] = \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb E[ X_i^j] = \sum_{j=1}^n 1 \cdot P(X_i^j)$$

$$ = \sum_{j=1}^n P(\text{jth outcome occurs $i$ times })$$

$$= \sum_{j=1}^n ~^mC_i~( p_j)^i (1-p_j)^{N-i} \cdot P(N = m)$$

$$= \sum_{j=1}^n ~^mC_i~( p_j)^i (1-p_j)^{N-i} \cdot e^{-\lambda} \dfrac{\lambda^m}{m!}$$

Did I approach this problem correctly? My approach looks complicated and I am not sure if I am on the right track. Help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: "Outcome $j$ occurs $i$ times", then shouldn't $j=1,2,\ldots,n$?

Comment: @SumanChakraborty Yes, my bad. I am correcting it. Could you also please advise about the rest of the problem